# Which permissions are needed for Google Cloud Natural Language API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

I am trying to find out which exact permissions are needed to access the Google Cloud Natural Language API. I have gone through the Quick Start https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/setup. Docs suggest to use role "Owner" but for production "more granular" permissions. But they don't mention which are these granular permissions.

Someone has already asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296656/iam-roles-for-google-cloud-natural-language-api). And the answer seems to be to give the AutoML rights. But If I understand correctly, there are 2 types of Natural Language services.

1. AutoML Natural Language
2. Natural Language API

I am trying to use the second service, not the AutoML Natural Language. So I am not sure if we still need to give the permission for AutoML?

I did go through the permission list [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) but did not find anything related to Natural Language API.

Comment: If the answer helped somehow consider upvoting/accepting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are some products like **Vision**, **Translate**, **Tables** and **Natural Language** that are classified as **AutoML**. This classification also includes all of these product's APIs.

Being this the case, as suggested in the other post, you can choose among these [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#automl-roles)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ML APIs on GCP are very clear about no role needed. Eg: [video-intelligence](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/quickstart#before_you_begin) says a service account with no roles.

NL API is probably the same way (no roles needed). If you can call the api with an api key, then you know no role is needed because api keys can't have roles.